# Why does my flask unit test not use a tempfile database when I had specified so?

Tags: python, flask

The test still writes to my MySQL database instead of a sqlite tempfile db. Why does this happen? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
class UserTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = get_app()
        #declare testing state
        self.app.config["TESTING"] = True
        self.db, self.app.config["DATABASE"] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        #spawn test client
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        #temp db
        init_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db)
        os.unlink(self.app.config["DATABASE"])

    def test_save_user(self):
        #create test user with 3 friends
        app_xs_token = get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
        test_user = create_test_user(APP_ID, app_xs_token)
        friend_1 = create_test_user(APP_ID, app_xs_token)
        friend_2 = create_test_user(APP_ID, app_xs_token)
        friend_3 = create_test_user(APP_ID, app_xs_token)
        make_friend_connection(test_user["id"], friend_1["id"], test_user["access_token"], friend_1["access_token"])
        make_friend_connection(test_user["id"], friend_2["id"], test_user["access_token"], friend_2["access_token"])
        make_friend_connection(test_user["id"], friend_3["id"], test_user["access_token"], friend_3["access_token"])

        save_user(test_user["access_token"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This line might be the problem:

```
self.db, self.app.config["DATABASE"] = tempfile.mkstemp()
```

`print` out the values of `self.db` and `self.app.config["DATABASE"]` and makes sure they are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to investigate where your config `self.app.config["DATABASE"]` is referenced in your database code.

The Flask example code usually does a lot of work when the module is first imported. This tends to break things when you try to dynamically change values at run time, because by then its too late.

You probably will need to use an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/#app-factories) so your app isn't built before the test code can run. Also, the app factory pattern implies you are using the [Blueprint interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/) instead of the direct `app` reference, which is acquired using a [circular import](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/#simple-packages) in the example code.